# How to implement a floating action button in a dialog activity

Tags: android, dialog, floating-action-button

I want my application to look somewhat like the starbuck app.

[image]

I want to start with the floating action button. I creating the activity layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fabPuntos"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:src="@android:color/transparent"
app:backgroundTint="#CCCC00" >
```

My java code

```
public class PuntosActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puntos);
}
```

}

and I have declared the activity in the manifest like this

```
<activity android:name=".PuntosActivity"
        android:label="TUS PUNTOS"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

I got the following error. What is the matter?

```
08-15 00:17:05.066 9930-9930/com.cerveceriacc.clientappv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cerveceriacc.clientappv2, PID: 9930
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cerveceriacc.clientappv2/com.cerveceriacc.clientappv2.PuntosActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:461)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2737)
    at com.cerveceriacc.clientappv2.PuntosActivity.onCreate(PuntosActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
    at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:164)
    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:158)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:461) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2737) 
    at com.cerveceriacc.clientappv2.PuntosActivity.onCreate(PuntosActivity.java:12) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Logcat

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

This describes your problem.

In your **PuntosActivity** you have used Theme **Theme.Dialog** which is not AppCompat Theme. Try using any AppCompat theme.

Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` as Activity Theme.

```
<activity android:name=".PuntosActivity"
    android:label="TUS PUNTOS"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
```